# Find a word and return specific value of the word

Tags: java, r.java-file

I have a file with this content:

```
1.10.100.1        1000.0
1.10.100.2        2000.0
1.10.100.3        2000.0
1.10.500.4        1000.0
```

i wrote the function that find the specific string in the file:

```
public double searchInBalance(String depositNumber) {
    try {
        String[] words = null;
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String string;
        String inputBalanceToFind = depositNumber;
        while ((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            words = string.split("        ");
            for (String word : words) {
                if (word.equals(inputBalanceToFind)) {
                    System.out.println("string :" + string);
                }
            }
        }
        fileReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error in searchInBalance");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

i want to make a function that when  find the left value of the file return the right value(the double value) back but have no idea how to do that please help me

Comment: Just store the values you read in a hashmap with key being the left column and value being the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public double searchInBalance(String depositNumber){

        try {
            String[] words = null;
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String string;
            String inputBalanceToFind = depositNumber;
            while ((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                words = string.split("        ");

                for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i += 2) {
                    if (words[i].equals(inputBalanceToFind)) {
                       System.out.println(words[i]+" - "+words[i - 1]);
                    }
                }

            }
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error in searchInBalance");
        }
    }
```

Just make a for loop with a counter to work with the indexes of the Array. But this is not a good programming style and you should try to improve your solution :D